# As Mapuche, does capturing a civilian unit lower enemy loyalty?

Tags: civilization-6-rise-and-fall

Enemy cities loyalty is lowered when one of their units dies inside their borders of that city, but do civilian units reduce their loyalty when captured?

Comment: Playing as them now, haven't had an opportunity to try this though. I did notice that if your archer is outside the enemy city borders and kills a unit inside their city borders the city doesn't lose loyalty. BOTH units must be in the city's borders for his trait to proc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capturing a civilian (builder) did **not** reduce the loyalty of the city-state I was at war with. Just to make sure I did kill one of their units and it did lower the loyalty of the city-state so it's not because I tested this on a city-state.